# Will this script safely (un)mount an NTFS partition for a swapfile?

Tags: bash, mount, scripts, steam, swap

I am using a persistent live USB running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Bionic Beaver, as [partitioning my hard drive is very difficult](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187988/can-i-install-ubuntu-linux-onto-the-hard-drive-of-my-lenovo-g570-laptop). When playing Steam games, I need a swapfile. [With help from](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188041/is-it-possible-to-create-an-ubuntu-swapfile-on-an-ntfs-partition?noredirect=1#comment1986529_1188041) @malte-skoruppa, I am now using a swapfile on an NTFS partition on the internal hard drive.

I would now like to automate the process using my first Bash script, based on [a HOWTO](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-and-unmount-file-systems-in-linux/). Can you see any flaws in this script, please?:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Mounting partition..."
sudo mount -U 80EA3F58EA3F49A4 /media/ubuntu/LENOVO
echo "Opening swapfile..."
sudo swapon /media/ubuntu/LENOVO/swapfile.img
steam steam://open/minigameslist
echo "Closing swapfile..."
sudo swapoff /media/ubuntu/LENOVO/swapfile.img
echo "Unmounting partition..."
sudo umount -l /media/ubuntu/LENOVO
echo "Mission accomplished!"
```

I am especially concerned about the `umount -l` option. The HOWTO says that it will unmount the partition once it's not busy, but [an old Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/96288/9721173) says that it force-unmounts the partition, which is **NOT** what I want to do.

Comment: You don't need that `-l` switch for `umount`. As the man page of `umount` says, "(...) The recommended use-case for umount -l is to prevent hangs on shutdown due to an unreachable network share (...)". You can simply use `umount /media/ubuntu/LENOVO`, without that option. Don't worry. It's not going to destroy anything on the partition, but finish all pending I/O operations first. It's like the "Safely remove hardware" icon on Windows. ;) Another flaw that I see in your script is that all commands are executed in sequence, without any checks whether the previous command was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Since I know you're new to Ubuntu, here's a few general comments.

**1. Put that partition in your `/etc/fstab`**

First off, in your script you use the line `sudo mount -U 80EA3F58EA3F49A4 /media/ubuntu/LENOVO` to mount your NTFS partition. I would suggest to add that partition to your `/etc/fstab` and map it to the UID of your partition there. Since you're on a single-user system, you may want to have an entry similar to this in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=80EA3F58EA3F49A4 /media/ubuntu/LENOVO ntfs rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0002,nls=utf8,noauto  0  0
```

Most importantly, this tells the system to bind the mount point `/media/ubuntu/LENOVO` to the UID `80EA3F58EA3F49A4`. That way, in the future (and thus in your script) you can simply use `sudo mount /media/ubuntu/LENOVO` instead of `sudo mount -U 80EA3F58EA3F49A4 /media/ubuntu/LENOVO`. If the UID changes in the future (because you reformat the partition), it's better to have only one central place, `/etc/fstab`, to edit rather than 20 scripts you may have lying around.

This also mounts the filesystem with various common options for NTFS partitions: read-write mode (`rw`), permit the execution of binaries (`exec`), make all files and directories on the file system belong to the user 1000 and group 1000 (`uid=1000,gid=1000`) (that's your normal user), set the permissions bits for all files and directories to 775 (`umask=0002`), set the character set for filenames to UTF-8 (`nls=utf8`), and do not mount the partition automatically (`noauto`). Refer to [fstab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) and [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) for more information. I personally find it convenient on my single-user system to be able to access all files on my NTFS partitions without having to use `sudo`, but of course your mileage may vary.

You may also want to drop the `noauto` option. Then, the partition will be mounted whenever the command `mount -a` is run, and in particular, at boot time (and thus, it would typically be mounted the whole time). Then you wouldn't even have to use the `mount` and `umount` commands in your script at all, but I don't know if you want that.

**2. Don't use `umount` with `-l`**

From [umount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/umount.8.html):

> The recommended use-case for umount -l is to prevent hangs on shutdown due to an unreachable network share where a normal umount will hang due to a downed server or a network partition.

So this option is at least rather unusual to use in your case.

Whether you run `umount` with or without `-l`, a partition will not be force-unmounted (there's the `-f` option for that). Rather, when you don't use `-l` and the partition is still busy, the unmount will simply fail and return an error message; when using `-l` and the partition is still busy, it will be detached from the filesystem hiearchy now (meaning you cannot access it anymore), but pending I/O operations will be silently completed in the background.

Since there shouldn't be any pending I/O operations after you've run `swapoff`, by not using `-l` you would at least notice if something is odd, because if the partition is unexpectedly still busy then the unmount command would output an error message.

**3. Add error handling**

You execute all commands in sequence, but don't check whether the previous command worked. So, e.g., if the mounting fails, then the `swapon` command will be nevertheless attempted but fail, and then your game will start even though the swap was not activated.

Try this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Mounting partition..."
sudo mount /media/ubuntu/LENOVO

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Could not mount partition, mission aborted." >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "Opening swapfile..."
sudo swapon /media/ubuntu/LENOVO/swapfile.img

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Could not activate swap, mission aborted." >&2
    exit 1
fi

steam steam://open/minigameslist

echo "Closing swapfile..."
sudo swapoff /media/ubuntu/LENOVO/swapfile.img

echo "Unmounting partition..."
sudo umount /media/ubuntu/LENOVO

echo "Mission accomplished!"
```